# Magento - Disabling configurable product options by store view

Tags: magento

I am trying to figure out a way that I can disable some of the simple products or configurable product options by store view in magento.

For example say a configurable product has 5 color options (5 simple products) associated with it. I need to be able to use that configurable product in in multiple stores but only offer specific color options based on the store. So store 1 could have it in only 3 colors while store 2 could have the other 2 colors available.

I tried to unassign the simple associated products I dont want to display in each store but all configurable options are still avaliable in all stores.

Anyone have any ideas or experience with this?

Comment: Only for completeness: Did you reindex and refresh cache?